# Express: Is it necessary to respond with status 200?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, server

Is it necessary to respond with a status `200` code or is it the default behavior?

```
response.json({
  status: 'OK',
});
```

vs.

```
response
  .status(200)
  .json({
    status: 'OK',
  });
```

When I hit the route in my browser, I get a 200 response in both cases

[image]

By now, I only use status code for other responses than 200 (e.g. 404, 500)

Comment: I wouldn't say it is necessary, but it certainly is the convention.

Comment: No, it is not necessary. The former does so without calling .status(200). Why ask if you've already confirmed this?

Comment: I'd say it's more of a best practice kinda thing... Personally... But no, it's not compulsory by any means.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for your answer. I was asking because I was not sure about my statement and could not find any answer in the express documentation nor somewhere else. Everyone is using it differently and I was looking for a best practice and even if there might be still some benefit from one over the other

Comment: it's not at all a "best practice"... it's just a method you can call if you so choose to. it isn't necessary, you can accept the default, or pass a value to ensure it is what you want it to be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Express response object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) wraps the underlying [Node.js response object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse). In Node.js, if you don't set a response, [it will always be `200`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#http-status-code). Express operates the same way for most requests. It will also automatically handle setting some error response codes for you depending on if and where an error was thrown.

Further, Express will set the response code for you on certain types of routes, for example, if you've [defined a redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect), it will automatically set the `302` code for you.